# Formatting messed up when piping wp commands

Tags: wp-cli

Ok, so I have been using `wp plugin update --all` in the past with a tee command. There has been no problem in the past, but after I ran an update on my system, everytime I run the command through a pipe, the formatting is messed up.
So this is the gist of the command used:
`wp plugin update --all|awk '/Success/,EOF'| tee >(convert -font Courier -pointsize 14 label:@- img.png)`
Previously it would produce a flawless output:
[image]

However, now when I pipe, even if I leave out the convert command, say something like this:
`wp plugin update --all | tee test.txt' the output is messed up....
[image]

or

[image]

Has anyone got any ideas....driving me a bit crazy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WP CLI needs to know some things about the terminal it's running in to format the table, aka the TTY.

But when you pipe, there is no TTY!

But you can trick it into thinking there is if you use this bash function:

```sh
faketty() {                       
    0</dev/null script --quiet --flush --return --command "$(printf "%q " "$@")" /dev/null
}
```

then you can run WP CLI commands and it will think it’s running in an interactive shell, not a pipe, e.g.:

```sh
faketty wp post list | more
```

Comment: Hi Tom. Thanks this did definitely help and worked! Thanks so much for the answer.
I think what got me, was that it was working before, and then suddenly it stopped. Not sure if this was a change on the wp cli side of things?
Anyway, I'm just grateful that it's now working - awesome help!!!!

Comment: WP CLI maintainers will be able to answer that either on their github or in the WP CLI slack channel on the official WP slack

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SHELL_PIPE` ENV variable to  preserve the ascii format, according to the WP-CLI [docs](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/references/internal-api/wp-cli-utils-ispiped/#notes):

> To enable ASCII formatting even when the shell is piped, use the ENV
> variable SHELL_PIPE=0.

For a single WP-CLI command this might be sufficient, e.g.:

```
( SHELL_PIPE=0; wp plugin list > list.txt )
```

or

```
( SHELL_PIPE=0; wp plugin list | less )
```

to preserve the ascii table format when piping. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10856211/2078474) is helpful regarding subshell.

Comment: For this to work, remove the semicolon from the command. See https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues/1102#issuecomment-258320233

Comment: Thank you @sun. Much cleaner and obvious this way. Final looks like this for me:
`(SHELL_PIPE=0 wp plugin list ) |& tee -a ~/pluginList.txt`